# How do you get the day of the week of strtottime in PHP?

Tags: php, database, date, unix-timestamp

I'd like to think I can see what day it is when I have a strtottime. I used now namely "4-April-2016". I have this date order changed from "2015-04-16" to 4-Apr-2016" 
For this I used this:(PHP)

```
echo date("d-F-Y ", strtotime($row["Datum"]));
```

Now I would recommend this to "Wednesday 4 Apr"(This is nicer in my styling)

I have in the database type "date" used.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: If you ask a question we can understand you will get an answer you can understand. Check what you have actually said and fix the anomilies then we will have a go. `date order changed from "2015-04-16" to 4-Apr-2016"` does not make sense

Comment: ??? No clue what you mean

Comment: what you want is ?? ... echo date("l d-F ", strtotime($row["Datum"]));

Comment: @CaioNardi That is what I want. Is it also possible that your "Tuesday"
turned into dutch or if that is not possible? 
thank you in advance

Comment: @William see `setlocale` function of php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a date in standard format "2015-04-04" and you want it changed to a different format?

You can do this in PHP:

```
date("l M j", strtotime($row["Datum"]));
```

Or directly from the database:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Datum, "%W %e %b") AS Datum;
```